# Increasing stack size of Code::Blocks 16.01

Tags: c++

I have a problem setting stack size of Code:Blocks 16.01.

I had to code a DFS by recursion that has a depth of 100,000 and it gets overflowed in my computer. I thought it was a stack problem, so I tried some stuffs to increase the stack size but all failed.

I tried putting -Wl,--stack,268435456 << this in linker settings but it failed.
Does anyone know how to increase the stack size of Code::Blocks? I use Windows.

sorry for my bad english

Comment: A recursion depth of 100,000?! You're having a laugh, right?

Comment: What Bathsheba is trying to say is that trying to have a stack that large is going to overflow pretty much any computer; not just your compurer.  If you have to recurse then you want to try and limit it to a very small number for exactly this reason.  If you can't get an alorithm that needs log(N) recursions then you're using either the wrong algorithm or the wrong implementation (ie you shouldn't recurse)